# jquery slider not displayed on page

Tags: jquery, uislider

I am trying to write a page using a jquery slider but the slider will not show up on the page

I have set up a jsfiddle to demo this

http://jsfiddle.net/andieje/2WGPv/

The external resource does say the slider is listed in the jquery.ui

When i run the page itself in a browser I get this error

```
Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function index.php:59
(anonymous function)
```

which refers to this bit here - the first line of the jquery

```
 $(function() {
```

Many thanks for your help

Please can you advise what I am doing wrong.

Comment: You're missing a `}` at the end of your function. http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/kqzw7/

Comment: Are you sure jQuery is loaded, and without any no-conflict options? The JSFiddle page is loading it for you, so the problem wouldn't be evident there.

Comment: You are using a different version of jquery to me. The missing } was just a copy and paste error, surely not worthy of a downvote. But yours works because you are using jquery 1.9.1 with jquery 1.9.2 checked. Why didnt my version work with version 1.10 and jquery ui as an external resource?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to include the `jQuery UI CSS` as well. I updated [your fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2WGPv/2/) using the CSS theme "ui-lightness" as an example.

Comment: I got my code to work locally like so:  <!-- Load jQuery and jQuery UI -->
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  
  <!-- Load the jQuery UI CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" /> Was the missing css the problem?

Comment: Are you saying it's fixed or not fixed? I'm saying without the CSS, there's no slider. After adding the CSS, the slider appears.

Here's another version with the `smoothness` theme: http://jsfiddle.net/rodgolpe/2WGPv/3/